# Headphone amplifiers for studio

Tags: headphone

Hello everyone,

I am researching headphone amplifiers at the moment and have found some suppliers but since we are an educational facility, I am looking for a 4 channel out headphone amp that is quite rugged and will hopefully stand the impact of numerous students using it.

I am not looking at the cheap stuff but reasonable quality amps so that musicuans and actors can listen to feeds and playback.

Any suggestions based on experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://artproaudio.com/artcessories/headphone_amps/product/headamp_4/

http://www.amazon.com/ART-HeadAmp4-Channel-Headphone-Amplifier/dp/B000M0TN6U

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any amps with four jacks, but myself I'm very fond of Violectric!

Answer (score 0):

I have got the Presonus HP4 and I find it splendid.

Answer (score 0):

I have the original Aphex headpod in my studio for several years. It is in a metal chassis and can really take a beating. It has 4 outputs the sound quality is good. Extremely happy with it, and will probably buy these for life.

Here is a link for the new model(which is assume is as good as the one I have):
http://www.aphex.com/aphex-products/headpod-4-2/

Aphex supposedly made it because they were not happy about anything on the market at the time:
http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/jun08/articles/aphexheadpod.htm

Answer (score 0):

We use the Rane HC6s which works really well and is nice and clean.

You can configure the amp so that it is 1 in 6 out, 6 in 6 out, or any other combination.

http://www.rane.com/hc6s.html

Answer (score 0):

Been using the [Samson C-que 8](http://www.samsontech.com/samson/products/processors/c-class/cque8/)
for years now. I've used it in the studio and also on location.